# Cannot build my solution in umbraco 7.7.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco. I built the website and everything was working fine until i build the solution for some reason `all.generated.cs` and `models.generated.cs` both are thinking everything in website is duplicate.

Cannot figure out what is wrong.
Attached are the snapshots from visual studio:
[image]

Comment: can you paste here your models builder configuration? It's on the web.config

Comment: @MarioLopez I excluded all.generated.cs and models.generated.cs from the project and now I am getting error.

Comment: Can you paste here your Models Builder Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

exclude both files (all.generated.cs and models.generated.cs) from vs project.
FYI: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-8025#tab=Similar%20Issues